# Is it possible to use a schema for a marshmallow custom field?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, marshmallow

Let's say that I have a `UserSchema`:

```
class UserSchema(ma.ModelSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'fullname')
```

and I have another Object Model `Group` that has a many-to-many relation with `User` and a method to return a subset of its users:

```
class Group(db.Model):
    ...


    def get_active_members(self):
        active_members = ...
        return active_members
```

I'm now try to write the marshmallow schema to serialize the `Group` model including also the active members.

I know that I can use a [custom field](http://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/custom_fields.html#custom-fields) but if I do:

```
class GroupSchema(ma.ModelSchema):
    members = fields.Function(lambda obj: obj.get_active_members())
```

I get is an error telling me that the `User` object is not serializable

> TypeError: Object of type 'User' is not JSON serializable

If I try to use a [nested field](http://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nesting.html) instead it just doesn't return anything since `get_active_members` is not a field.

Is there a way to return the active members in this case?

A possible solution I have found:

```
class Group(db.Model):
    ...

    @property
    def members(self):
        return get_active_members()

    def get_active_members(self):
        active_members = ...
        return active_members 

class GroupSchema(ma.ModelSchema):
    members = fields.Nested(UserSchema, dump_only=True)
```

But I'm not really sure if this is how Marshmallow should work.

Comment: `members = fields.Function(lambda obj: UserSchema(many=True).dump(obj.get_active_members()).data)`

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how/what exactly you are trying to serialize but a common mistake I see people make with Marshmallow schema is to serialize the schema itself, forgetting that the schema holds no data and hence  serializing it gives an error. Here's an example of a nested schema:

```
from marshmallow import *

class UserSchema(Schema):
    class Meta:
        fields = ('email', 'fullname')

class GroupSchema(Schema):
    users = fields.Nested(UserSchema, many=True)
```

So, to serialize data with this schema I'd do:

```
data = {"users": [{"fullname": "Mr. Bean", "email": "mr@bean.com"}, {"fullname": "James Bond", "email": "james@bond.com"}]}

schema = GroupSchema()
schema.dumps(data)
```

Which gives

```
MarshalResult(data='{"users": [{"email": "mr@bean.com", "fullname": "Mr. Bean"}, {"email": "james@bond.com", "fullname": "James Bond"}]}', errors={})
```

Comment: My problem is that I don't have a users attribute in the Group model. I have only a method that gives me a list of active members.